# Don't know how to export report in sonarqube 6.0

Tags: pdf, export

I checked all through the web, but can't find any way to export report to pdf. 
5.6.1 version, I heard that i can use governor plugin to export report. 
but once I put it in plugin directory in sonarqube6.0 and anaylize, prompt show me error like this,

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project euTemplate: Unable to register extension com.sonar.governance.task.A.A from plugin 'governance': Lorg/sonar/batch/bootstrap/BatchWsClient;: org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient -> [Help 1]

I think it's because of version....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no free plugin available to generate an executive level report. You need to go to https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Governance+Plugin and https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/plugins/governance.html then purchase an Enterprise edition from Sonarsource to enable the Governance plugin. (You can also get the trial version for two weeks)

Comment: Is there any possible way or any workaround to generate Sonar analysis PDF report without Governance Plugin for Sonar 6.7.3 or 7.1 version?

Comment: @Krimi Nope there isn't!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install and use the governance plugin of SonarSource, you have to contact SonarSource and buy a Enterprise plan license.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when upgrading to SonarQube 6.0. I contacted SonarSource and apparently the Governance plugin is not compatible with SonarQube 6.0 yet, only with the LTS version.